# How to compare strings in python?

Tags: python, string, compare, string-comparison

I need to store a string in an array of elements, when I store and compare back they are not same. I am not sure what I am missing.

```
test = np.zeros(1,dtype=[('data','a8')]) 

test['data']=str("right") 
print(test[0]['data'], test[0]['data'] == "right")
```

my output is `b'right' False`. It should be `True`, though.

Comment: `b'right' != 'right'`; you need to `.decode` the bytes with the appropriate encoding to compare to the string. For example, `b'right'.decode('utf8') == 'right'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings and bytes (note the b in the printout). Try

```
print(test[0]['data'] == b"right")
```

Comment: No problem. You should accept the answer if you're satisfied.